# How to create a product with multiple selections in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, multi-select

I am setting up a shop site using Woocommerce and need to put together a product assortment for taffy. I need to be able to allow the customer to customize the flavors to be included in the assortment. Is there a way to have a multi select for flavors? And provide % options as well that totals to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably do best setting up simple products and then assemble one grouped product that includes simple products to best display the assortment.

Flavors would be set up as an attribute for variable products.

- Flavor 1: Strawberry, Lemon, Orange
- Flavor 2: Strawberry, Lemon, Orange

Percent options (also attribute for variable products) would probably be best in chunks.

- Percent 1: 10%, 20%, 30%, etc.
- Percent 2: 10%, 20%, 30%, etc.

Then you set the variable products individually so you could combine a flavor and a percent the person could choose.

- Strawberry: 10%, Lemon:30%, etc.

http://www.woothemes.com/products/composite-products/

Composite products looks like it would give you greater control. Probably would be a bit less clunky too.

I'm not sure if WooCommerce is the perfect outlet for that kind of product. Definitely would be a trial/error.

Comment: Aibrean:Thank you for your suggestion. I tried that and you are right, it looks really clunky as I have up to 12 flavor selections and percents showing as drop downs. I will take a look at the composite product option. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know. Thank you!